# changing position of background image which appears after a hover html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, mousehover

EDIT: background-position does change the position of the background image. I realized the actual problem I am facing is something else, which can be seen on this thread:
[Background image disappears when changing its background-position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215885/css-background-image-disappears-when-changing-its-background-position)

Okay so I have a set of links (a href's)  inside an unordered list, and when the user hovers over them, I want a black background image to show up on top of the link and change the links color to black. I already have the background image which shows up photoshoped. Here is what I did so far

```
li:hover {
    color: white;
    background: url(../images/liHover.png);
}
```

Now, the problem is that the image doesn't show where I want it to show. I want the link to be in the center of the image. The image is like 3 pixels below where I actually want it to be. It is the same for which ever link I hover over, the image is always 3 pixels below where I want it to be. Is there a way to change the position of the image which shows up and a way to move that image a few pixels above where it is normally supposed to be? (even if we cannot do this with CSS, if someone can write a Javascript function which can get this accomplished, that would be great).

The list is just

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't get the point, could you add the code of your list?

Comment: can you not use background-position?

Comment: or make the image the same size as the element or vice versa

Comment: background-position should work 100%. if not I'll eat my hat

Comment: For some reason when I change background position, the image position itself won't move, but instead, it's like there is a container with the image and the image moves up inside the container, so if I make the image move up 20px, it will just disapear.. If I move it up 5px, the image will move up 5px inside it's weird container but the position of the image / container won't move.

Comment: @Dean_Wilson I tried making the image the same size as the li, it is still giving me the same problem. The image is 340x40 and it's like it's inside a container 340x40 placed incorrectly on the screen. So when I try to reposition it using background-position, the image will move inside the container, it wont move relative to the screen. It's like I can only see the image if it is inside the container.

Comment: okay so turns out that background-position does work but the problem I am facing was something else, which can be seen on this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215885/css-background-image-disappears-when-changing-its-background-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you mean:

```
li:hover {
  color: white;
  background: url(../images/liHover.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

if it doesn't center the way you want, play with the `center center` values which are x / y (horizontal / vertical). they can be also px,em or % values.

Comment: hm okay this does center the image and it does reposition it if I play with the x / y values so it does answer the question. I realized that my actual problem was something else, it can be seen on this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215885/css-background-image-disappears-when-changing-its-background-position